# Assigning a value to a float variable changes the value in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I am trying to calculate an average of integer numbers and assign it to a `float` variable. When I debug it with `cgdb` and print the right side of the average calculation, it gives me the right number.  However, when I assign it to the `(float*)payload` the value changes from `401850471` to `401850464.00`.

```
float sum= 0.0;

for (int i = 0;
     i<avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->num_tuples; 
     i++) {
     sum+= ((int*)avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->payload)[i];     
}

((float*)avg_operator->result->payload)[0]=
sum/(float)avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->num_tuples;
```

Comment: don't cast the pointer, cast the value.

Comment: Don,t use float - it does not have enough precision to handle nine significant digits. Use double instead.

Comment: Couldn't you usefully use a local variable of the correct type to save having to write `avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result` multiple times.  It would save people a load of reading, too.  And the casts are dubious.

Comment: Provide the declaration of `num_tuples, payload` and detail of how data is printed to achieve even better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert an int to a float by casting their pointers, that gives a random / undefined value. You need to dereference the float pointer, and assign the *value*.

Answer (score 1):

that:

```
((float*)avg_operator->result->payload)[0]= sum/(float)avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->num_tuples;
```

isn't casting, it's *lying to the compiler*. You should dereference, and no need to cast to float, as the conversion to integer is done automatically:

```
avg_operator->result->payload[0]= sum/(float)avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->num_tuples;
```

(well, maybe you need to round the value instead of truncating, though)

also, since `payload` is an integer, no need to cast to integer pointer as well, just do:

```
sum+= avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->payload[i];
```

and define `sum` as a float, one never knows with floating point accumulation error (if the sum isn't too big for an integer, that is)

Answer (score 0):

> When I debug it with cgdb and print the right side of the average calculation, it gives me the right number.

The debugger is showing the quotient using `double` math.  C allows `float` division to use wider types.  But once the quotient is assigned to a `float`, precision narrowing may occur.

---

`401850471` is a 29 bit value.  A `float` typically has 24 bits of precision.  Something must give.

401850464.0 is the closest representable `float` to 401850471, so that speaks well to that at least there is a reasonable result.

---

OP is also doing other strange code manipulations.  A recommend solution begins with a wider `sum` type and more precise division and storage.

```
long long sum = 0.0;

int n = avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->num_tuples
int *data = (int*)avg_operator->data_source->column_pointer.result->payload;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  sum += data[i];
}

double average = 1.0 * sum / n;
printf("Average %f\n", average);
```

---

If the answer must be a `float`, code must live with a rounded (in a binary sense) average.